# Where to store resources for a java project in Eclipse (images, data files, ...)?

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, directory

Not sure this basic question has already been answered on SO.

From the reference and also answers found on SO, I understand that in Eclipse a "source folder" is a folder that JDT will search for source files, and compile them.

It has been mentioned also that each source folder may have a counterpart to store compiled classes. Maybe this is why the content of the usual "src" folder of a project is compiled into a "bin" folder (when using such src/bin project option in Eclipse).

**Question**: Where to store additional non-source files, e.g. an icon, a security policy, or a data file? I guess this is in a "regular" folder, but at which level in the project hierarchy (usually)? Is it possible to put it in a source folder or not (why would we do that)? What happens after compilation, or export to a .jar file, under which conditions are the files copied in the .jar? Is the relative path preserved?

Comment: you can put them in inside src folder

Comment: often put such things into a \assets folder, parallel to \src folder ... depending on how you are going to deploy the resulting program.

Comment: @ErstwhileIII: Thanks. Can you say more about "depending on how..."? What are the criteria you think about?

Comment: Will the Java program run on your own computer, on a Web Server, as an Android application .. all final deployments may have requirements of their own as to where programs and files they access need to reside.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is purely conventional. You can store them all in `src` if you want.

However, if you want to stick to Maven or Gradle conventions, then you should have something like that:

- `src/main/java` : main source file, that will be compiled and then distributed (jar, etc)
- `src/main/resources` : main resources, distributed.
- `src/test/java` : test source file, aka Junit test
- `src/test/resources` : test resources.

Maven would compile all Java into `target/classes` and copy all resources into `target/classes`. For test, it would be `target/test-classes`.

Beside, if you want to access a resource, that in the Jar where your classes are, you should not use `new File("...")` or `Paths.get(...)` but [getResourcesAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) or its counterpart [getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29):

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/myfile.txt"))) {
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
  }
}
```

This would probably throw a NPE if `/myfile.txt` was not found.