# Where to store documentation inside an Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, documentation

I'm writing a small piece of software with Eclipse. Like [Pat Notz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537/what-tools-are-used-to-write-documentation) I'm using Latex to write my documentation and want to have them inside my Eclipse project. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712499/where-to-store-resources-for-a-java-project-in-eclipse-images-data-files) was mentioned, that I can use mostly every folder I want.
Are there in my case some special folders or is that a bad idea in general, to add documentation and code inside the same project?

Comment: Actually it is up to your decision where to store those documents, Eclipse or Java has nothing to do with the folder name of documentations. But usually people tend to place them in `doc` or something.

Comment: I would put it in a doc directory under the project's root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What language are you using for your project? If you are using Java, you can use javadoc comments and then generate an API/documentation using `javadoc`. You are also free to put your documentation files anywhere you want. You can have one main file in your root directory, one file per folder, the sky is the limit!

Comment: I'm using Java. How to document is another topic. I'm thinking about how to write a  good documentation. Database has their own comments on tables and columns (== documentation). Javadoc is used to tell, how a function works. If you are running TDD, your test cases are an indicator how to use your API. So my documentation (a private project) is used as an short abstract about naming conventions and general aspects.

Comment: Javadoc is used for more than to explain how a function works. You can use it to explain what a class does, what it does not do, some implementation details, anything you want. Take a look at the [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface. It has information about the class, how to use, what it does, and many more things. For your case, you can use javadoc or a text file, wherever you see appropriate, to document the general aspects and naming conventions about your project.