# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" - maven/gradle

Tags: java

Here's code:

```
private whateva loadImage() throws IOException {

    whateva img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/1.jpg"));

    return img;
}
```

And here's what I get:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!

Screen of the project's files/packages:

[image: ScreenShot]

Have no idea what is wrong, tried to relocate image to other folders and still haven't worked out. What is more funny - when I compile it in NetBeans, it works. But when I try to compile this as a Maven or Gradle project, I've got this problem.

Comment: Hi @TheTeemoMan, welcome on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm not a Java expert, but I think you can find the answer somewhere around. Have you tried to put your images in the "src/main/resources" folder ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712499/where-to-store-resources-for-a-java-project-in-eclipse-images-data-files

Comment: Yup, tried it, still have this exception.
And yea, I looked for answer here but couldn't find any.

Comment: @Moose OK, I got this! And yeah, that was my fault because I totally ignored how file path should looks like when you use Maven. So I created new Maven project, then create new folder(in NetBeans -> right click in "other sources" -> folder) and then I paste my image there. It works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is obviously some difference between how the resource file is loaded between Netbeans and Maven/Gradle. You have to put your file in `src/main/resources/images/1.jpg` and it should work, unless you have some broken Maven/Gradle configuration or you are trying to run outside of a built jar file.

Comment: Tried it, still doesn't work. Imma try to find some tutorials to confiure Gradle/Maven properly.

Comment: OK, I got this! And yeah, that was my fault because I totally ignored how file path should looks like when you use Maven. So I created new Maven project, then create new folder(in NetBeans -> right click in "other sources" -> folder) and then I paste my image there. It works now, thanks!

Comment: @TheTeemoMan Please could you press the upvote button if my answer was helpful to you, or the tick button if it answered your question? Either of these will mean the question will be registered as "answered" in the system.